# How to change the format of a concat statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, concatenation

I use a concat statement to select the start and endtime inside my postgresql database.

Code:

```
SELECT
     CASE
        WHEN d.id = 4 THEN (SELECT CONCAT (i.start_time,  i.end_time) FROM rdf_date_time i, rdf_condition_dt h WHERE ...) 
        ELSE ''
    END as timedomain
FROM ..
JOIN ...;
```

start_time: 0500(5 a.m.)
end_time: 1300 (13p.m.)

The column timedomain looks like: 5002200

I will this format as the result: **[(h5){8}]** = [(start_time) {duration till end_time}]
How can I convert it this way?

Comment: you must format the time value in proper mode .. but this is db depending .. so tag your db model

Comment: this is not working because the columns end_time and start_time inside my db are characters.

Comment: `(i.end_time::time-i.start_time::time)` then?.. and if they are integers, `(i.end_time::text::time-i.start_time::text::time)`

Comment: it is written invalid syntax for type time: "500"

Comment: can I convert values like '500' in time format?

Comment: oh - I thought you have it `0500`, not `500`... what is the time mask?

Answer (score 1):

to calculate interval you should just extract one time from the other, eg:

```
t=# select '0500'::time-'1300'::time diff;
 diff
-----------
 -08:00:00
(1 row)
```

If you column is of type integer, you have to prepare it first, like here:

```
t=# select lpad(500::text,4,'0')::time;
   lpad
----------
 05:00:00
(1 row)
```

So for you smth like below should work:

```
(lpad(i.end_time::text,4,'0')::time - lpad(i.start_time::text,4,'0')::time)
```

Comment: thanks this is working now. the result is correct. I get 17:00:00. I need only the number of hours like in this case only '17' or for 30 min I need '0,3' Is this possible?